# How many targets can be hit by wall of lava?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

> This spell creates a vertical wall of lava that is 1 inch thick for
>   every 4 caster levels and composed of up to one 5-foot square per
>   level. A wall of lava's maximum height cannot exceed half of its width
>   (with a minimum height of 5 feet). The wall cannot be conjured so that
>   it occupies the same space as a creature or object. A section of a
>   wall of lava can be destroyed by damage (hardness 4, hp 90), but if a
>   section is destroyed, the remaining lava in the wall immediately fills
>   in any such hole created, reducing the wall's overall size by one
>   5-foot square but remaining a contiguous barrier. Each time a weapon
>   strikes a wall of lava, it takes 2d6 points of fire damage (or the
>   creature who strikes the wall takes 2d6 fire damage if the attack was
>   via an unarmed strike or natural attack).
>
> A creature can move through a wall of lava as a full-round action by
>   making a DC 25 Strength check—failure indicates that the creature is
>   pushed back out of the wall to the point he just attempted to leave. A
>   creature with a burrow speed can move through the wall using its
>   burrow speed. An attempt to move through a wall of lava inflicts 20d6
>   fire damage. A wall of lava also radiates heat as if it were a wall of
>   fire, although the heat from a wall of lava radiates from both sides.
>
> **Once per round as a move action, you can direct the wall of lava to
>   erupt. This causes a plume of lava to fire at any target within 60
>   feet of either side of the wall, but reduces the wall's overall size
>   by 1d4 5-foot square sections. You must make a ranged touch attack to
>   hit the target, which takes 10d6 points of fire damage on a hit. Holes
>   created in a wall of lava from this effect instantly reseal, reducing
>   the overall size of the wall.**
>
> All damage inflicted by physical contact with a wall of lava continues
>   for 1d3 rounds after exposure ceases, but this additional damage is
>   only half that dealt during actual contact (that is, 1d6 or 5d6 or
>   10d6 points per round).

<sup>([Source](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wall-of-lava), bolding added)</sup>

"*...This causes a plume of lava to fire at any target within 60 feet of either side of the wall,...*"

What does *any* in this case mean?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Any means one in this case.**

> Once per round as a move action, you can direct the wall of lava to erupt. This causes a plume of lava to fire at any target within 60 feet of either side of the wall, but reduces the wall's overall size by 1d4 5-foot square sections. You must make a ranged touch attack to hit the **target**, which takes 10d6 points of fire damage on a hit. Holes created in a wall of lava from this effect instantly reseal, reducing the overall size of the wall.

In the text after the quote you provided (from the Wall of Lava spell), there is a direct reference to the target once more in the singular form, suggesting that there is only one target of this effect. For the most part, assume that the text targets one unless it explicitly states that it targets multiple creatures or all in range.

Comment: Addendum: The typical wording for the other possible reading of "any target" is "all creatures", or "every creature".

Answer (score 0):

Any target normally means that it can harm anything, be it friend or foe. The spell effect area does not make a distinction between who is near or crossing the threshold.

In this instance however, the any is referring to **a singular target** of your choice within 60 feet of the wall itself.